# tic_tac_toe winnerSelection loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This is a Tutorial in Reactjs.org while creating a function for declaring a winner i encountered this logic!!!!

Is this "square[a]&&" logical error in the tutorial of Tic Tac Toe in reactjs.org it seems that the condition only should be `if(squares[a]===squares[b]&&squares[a]==squares[c]){ return square[a]; }` I am not understanding some logic myself or the code has logical error ?

Comment: `if(squares[a])` checks for the existence of that value.

Comment: Add more details. And clearly explain what is required and what is the actual question.

Comment: This is a Tutorial in Reactjs.org and while creating a function for declaring a winner i encountered this logic!!!!

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Enter the text, *for clarity*.

Comment: Sure, I will take it into consideration onwards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As others have stated, please edit your question to contain actual code, not an image link to a picture of code. Also: someone else has already explained what the first check is doing. In your question, it's hard to tell if you're running into any error (and we cannot see any other code, or output, or errors). If there is some specific question or issue, please edit to clarify. Otherwise, it seems like your misunderstanding was covered via the first comment here, posted by @BenBeck.

Comment: thankyou  @DavidMakagon and the first comment doesn't solve my question, his answer is correct to his logic, I have included full code now.. everybody will be more clear about the problem domain now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `const [a, b, c] = lines[i];` says assign to a, b and c the values of one of the lines.  Those are triplets of integers like `0,1,2` for the top row.

The condition in the OP:

```
if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c])
```

... indexes into the squares array with the three integers, so again for the first row, the condition is enquiring about the values of `squares[0]`, `squares[1]`, and `squares[2]`.

The question being asked is:

- is there any truthy value in square[0]?
- is that value the same as the value of square[1]?
- is that value the same as the value of square[2]?

The loop asks this question for each of the 8 lines - each of the 8 ways one can win the game